# Group the sum of sales of different customer age groups (SQL)

Tags: sql, sum, range

hoping someone can help me as I continue to learn sql.

I have a data set that contains sales of different customers as well as their respective ages.

My goal is to group together customer ages in intervals of 10 (40s, 50s, 60s, 70s, etc.) then show the sum of sales of each of those age groups.

[Here's what I was able to do so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKRUk.png)

I'm struggling with grouping together the age group and sales. Ideally, the result above would show an age range of 40-49 and the then entire sum of those sales.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Thanks in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to group the age ranges into another value.  Below, I will do this by dividing the customer's age by 10 to create clusters by decade.  I multiply by 10 again to get the decade for display in the output.

Imagining you have a 'customer' table and 'sales' table with the data...

customers data:

```
id  name           age
1   Tim          25
2   Mike         43
3   Gervase      37
4   Karthik      42
5   Tyler        58
6   Lucas        29
7   Amy          32
8   John         36
9   Tathiana     28
10  Charles      52
11  Milenka      24
12  Dave         41
13  Bill         54
14  Shirley      24
15  Wendy        22
16  Cyrus        33
```

sales data:

```
order_num   customer_id amount
1           5           5.00
2           3           10.00
3           12          15.00
4           7           5.00
5           8           15.00
6           13          10.00
7           5           11.00
8           8           12.00
9           12          7.00
10          8           3.00
11          11          5.00
12          14          10.00
13          1           15.00
14          3           16.00
15          16          15.00
16          15          14.00
```

```
     select concat( str(( c.age / 10 ) * 10), 's') as Age
          , count(s.order_num) as 'Number_of_sales'
          , sum(s.amount) as 'Total Sales'
          , round(AVG(s.amount),2) as 'Average Sale'
     from customers c join sales s on c.id = s.amount
     group by ( c.age / 10 )
```

Produces the following output...

```
    Age Number_of_sales Total   Average Sale
    20s 6               85.00   14.17
    30s 3               26.00   8.67
    40s 1               12.00   12.00
    50s 6               45.00   7.50
```